# Unwanted square brackets in json response

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have little problem with a PHP code that gives JSON response. Let me give you an example to be clear.
Let's say we have the following table in a database:

```
      | firstname | lastname | age |
      +===========+==========+=====+
      | Nick      | James    | 21  |
      +-----------+----------+-----+
      | John      | Manson   | 23  |
      +-----------+----------+-----+
```

In my PHP code the column names are stored in the array $col_fields. Number of columns is stored in the variable $num_fields. Array $row stores each row of the database table, so row[0] is the firstname, row[1] is lastname and row[2] is age. Also I use the auxiliary array $row_aux to store pairs: "key" => "value". So, in our example, the pairs will be the following:

row 1: "firstname" => "Nick", "lastname" => "James", "age" => "21"

row 2: "firstname" => "John", "lastname" => "Manson", "age" => "23"

**What I'm waiting as a JSON response is described here:**

{ "table_name" :[ { "firstname" : "Nick",  "lastname" : "James", "age" : 21}, { "firstname" : "John",  "lastname" : "Manson", "age" : 23}]}

**But What I' m really getting is described here:**

{ "table_name" :[ { "firstname" : **[**"Nick"**]**,  "lastname" : **[**"James"**]**, "age" : **[**"21"**]**}, { "firstname" : **[**"John"**]**,  "lastname" : **[**"Manson"**]**, "age" : **[**"23"**]**}]}

The code I used is:

```
while ($i < $num_fields) {
  $row_aux[$col_fields[$i]][] = $row[$i];
  $i++;
}
echo json_encode($row_aux);
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try to remove the last set of brackets from your code? seems like thats creating an array where you are pushing a single value:

```
while ($i < $num_fields) {
  $row_aux[$col_fields[$i]] = $row[$i];
  $i++;
}
echo json_encode($row_aux);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $row_aux[$col_fields[$i]][] = $row[$i];
                           ^^---append to array
```

Since `$i` increments each time, you're creating a brand new single-item array on every iteration. If that's only ever going to hold a single value, then rip out the `[]`:

```
  $row_aux[$col_fields[$i]] = $row[$i];
                           ^---just assign the value, no extra array
```